# How to loop in Racket?

Tags: racket

I want to loop this one until the nr-of-bread is 2 how to do it?

```
(when (and (>= money price-of-bread) (< nr-of-bread 2))
        (set! nr-of-bread (+ nr-of-bread 1)) (set! money (- money price-of-bread)))
```

Comment: `(quotient money price-of-bread)`

Comment: @uselpa rather `(min 2 (quotient money price-of-bread))`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that is using tail recursion via named `let`:

```
(let loop ((nr-of-bread 0)
           (rest money))
  (if (and (>= rest price-of-bread) (< nr-of-bread 2))
    (loop (add1 nr-of-bread) (- rest price-of-bread))
    nr-of-bread))
```

Comment: In Racket it's `add1`, not `1+`.

Comment: Oh… Fixed now. I have been testing it on MIT Scheme on which IIRC Racket is based so I thought that they also have `1+`. But still solves problem.

Comment: In Racket you shouldn't use `rest` as a variable name, it clashes with a built-in function.